# How to get mask from numpy array according to all values on third axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have numpy array like:

```
A = np.zeros((X,Y,Z))
```

Later I fill the array with values and I need to find x,y coordinates according to values in arrays on z axis to replace it with different array.

Example with`Z=2` I have array

```
A = [ [ [1,2], [2,1], [0, 0] ],
      [ [1,1], [1,1], [0, 0] ], ]
```

I need something like

```
A[ where A[x,y,:] == [1,2] ] = [2,1]
```

What will produce array

```
A = [ [ [2,1], [2,1], [0, 0] ],
      [ [1,1], [1,1], [0, 0] ], ]
```

Is it possible to achieve that somehow simple? I would like to avoid iteration over the x,y coordinates.

Comment: Could you add a sample case and the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar Done. If it is not enough, then let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One vectorized approach -

```
A[(A == [1,2]).all(-1)] = [2,1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: A
Out[15]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [0, 0]]])

In [16]: A[(A == [1,2]).all(-1)] = [2,1]

In [17]: A
Out[17]: 
array([[[2, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [0, 0]]])
```